# make org.springframework.security.oauth use com.fasterxml.jackson not org.codehouse.jackson

Tags: spring, maven, jackson, spring-data-rest, spring-security-oauth2

I have Spring project which uses `org.springframework.security.oauth`, `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` and `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Everything works well but I want to exclude some fields from domain objects using `@JsonIgnore` annotation. This doesn't work. I checked both:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` and  `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore`

My `mvn dependency:tree` shows:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
```

and

```
[INFO] org.springframework:na-punkty-data-rest:war:0.1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
```

and

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
```

I am not using any classes from `org.codehaus` or `com.fasterxml` directly in my code (I only try to use it with `@JsonIgnore` in one place). In my opinion I should get rid of doubling implementation and make `oAuth` use `com.fasterxml`. But I am not sure is it a good path and how to achieve it?

I tried to build `https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/` and use `@JsonIgnore` and it works there, but the `mvn dependency:tree` shows only one implementation for jackson mapper there (`com.fasterxml`).

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Good to hear you could solve your problem by fixing a typo. However, replacing `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl` with `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` is still an important task, I'd like to solve!

Answer (score 0):

Good evening,

I found the reason why `@JsonIgnore` didn't work. It was a typo :(

I had private field starting from a capital letter:

```
@JsonIgnore
private String Roles;
```

after changing it to

```
@JsonIgnore
private String roles;
```

it started working. Of course I had to use proper `@JsonIgnore` implementation, in this case it was `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore`

Sorry for posting this question. Everyting works good there. I was blind.

Answer (score 0):

The artefact `jackson-mapper-asl` belongs to Jackson 1 ("Codehaus"). To switch to `jackson-databind` you have to use Jackson 2 ("FasterXML").

In this specific situation, the dependency is brought in transitively by `spring-security-oauth`. Therefore you have to upgrade to version `2.4.0` - yet to be released on 2019-11-07.

The upgrade of Jackson 1 to 2 is done in this [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/996).